# Strong Class Objects inside for loop is not retaining in ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have an Manual Reference Count project, where few classes Im converting to ARC by removing retain,release & etc and by setting compiler flag “-fobjc-arc”
Their are 2 ARC(-fobjc-arc) enabled view controller classes, ClassA and ClassB.

I am allocating and initialising objects of ClassB inside ClassA within a for loop to achieve some functionality, Code snippet is as below,

```
@interface ClassA ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) ClassB *classBObj;

@end


@implementation ClassA

- (void)createClassBView {
    for (int count = 0; count <= [dataObject count]; count++) //if count is more than 1 it is not retaining the previous classBObj
    {
        classBObj = [[ClassB alloc] init]; //ARC is keeping only 1 object reference of this class but I need to retain all the iterated objects
        [self.scrollView addSubView:classBObj withFrame:myFrame];//only 1 view is getting added as subview even if control comes here more than once
    }
}

@end
```

The above code works fine for me in non-ARC(MRC) but fails to work properly when ARC is enabled. It is not retaining ClassB objects even if it is strong,

Only 1 object i.e; last iterated ClassB object reference is alive, rest are getting destroyed and it is throwing exception "ClassB reference to an deallocated instance"

I tried by using `if(!classBObj){classBObj = [[ClassB alloc] init];}` inside loop, that time I'm not getting ClassB reference to an deallocated instance exception but only 1 subview of ClassB is getting added to my scrollview(i.e; last iterated).

Please guide me on this.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Are you missing `self` as for `self.classBObj = ...`? What is inside of the method `-addSubView:withFrame:`?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do. You are setting the very same reference, `self.classBObj`, to a ClassB instance - over and over, in your loop. Each time through the loop, the existing ClassB instance that was previously assigned `self.classBObj` needs to "get out of the way" so that a new one can be assigned to `self.classBObj`. So it is rightly released when it is replaced by the new one - rightly, because there is now no existing reference to it.

The truth is that you were totally mismanaging the memory here before ARC, and adopting ARC has revealed this fact. You're just lucky your code ever worked (or seemed to). If you want to maintain multiple ClassB instances, you need your instance variable to be an *array* of them, not a *single* one.

(On the other hand, if `classBObj` is a UIView and is to be added immediately to the interface as a subview, that is still happening, so it's hard to see what your complaint is. Indeed, the weird part is why you ever needed `classBObj` to be a property in the first place; why isn't it just a local variable? It's not like you *need* these references to be retained elsewhere, since you *have* those references — as subviews of your `self.scrollView`. But if you need those references for some later purpose, and if you don't want to obtain them by using the fact that they are subviews of your scroll view, then clearly you need an array of them, as I just said.)

Comment: It should not be released if it is properly added as a subview to the scroll view at the last line.

Comment: @iMartin Of course it should be released. It should not be _destroyed_. Those are two completely different things; destruction happens only if the retain count reaches zero. (But of course I agree that we have no idea what's going on with the scroll view; that is why my third paragraph is a parenthetical aside, since for all I know, they are _not_ actually being added to the scroll view, though they are supposed to be. I have confined my main answer to the thing the OP asked about, namely the memory management.)

Comment: He says that previous instances are getting destroyed, which wouldn't make sense if they're getting added to the scroll view. Most likely, if only the most recent instance continues to exist, then `self.scrollView` must be `nil`, and the only thing keeping the most recent instance around is the property.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your well defined answer, It was really helpful for me, Yes I do want to maintain multiple ClassB instances, I need to initiate a mutable array outside the for loop and add the instance variable(classBObj) object, in to this array on each iteration? Is that what you mean? or you are saying something else? Thanks,

Comment: @Splendor_iOS That is certainly a reasonable approach. But, as others have pointed out, and as I hint in my answer, you must also ask yourself whether your `addSubView:withFrame:` is working as you expect.